# Jcombobox no se llena con datos de MySQL

Tags: java, mysql-workbench, combobox, mysqlconnector

Intento crear una GUI que cargue los datos de la base de datos sin embargo cuando lo ejecuto no arroja ningún error y no muestra absolutamente nada en el JcomboBox.
he revisado los parametros de mysql, tal como el nombre de l base de datos que sea igual, las tablas y el puerto sin embargo no consigo que muestre algo.

```
import java.sql.*;

public class tarea7 extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public tarea7() {
        initComponents();
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
    private void initComponents() {


        BotonImprimir = new javax.swing.JButton();
        BotonSalir = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jComboBoxCurso = new javax.swing.JComboBox<>();
        jLabelCurso = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jList1 = new javax.swing.JList<>();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jComboBoxZona = new javax.swing.JComboBox<>();
        jScrollPane2 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jList2 = new javax.swing.JList<>();
        jScrollPane3 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jList3 = new javax.swing.JList<>();
        jScrollPane4 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jList4 = new javax.swing.JList<>();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        BotonImprimir.setText("Imprimir");

        BotonSalir.setText("Salir");
        BotonSalir.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                BotonSalirActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jComboBoxCurso.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jComboBoxCursoActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jLabelCurso.setText("Curso");

        jList1.setModel(new javax.swing.AbstractListModel<String>() {
            String[] strings = { "Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4", "Item 5" };
            public int getSize() { return strings.length; }
            public String getElementAt(int i) { return strings[i]; }
        });
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jList1);

        jLabel1.setText("Zona");

        jList2.setModel(new javax.swing.AbstractListModel<String>() {
            String[] strings = { "Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4", "Item 5" };
            public int getSize() { return strings.length; }
            public String getElementAt(int i) { return strings[i]; }
        });
        jScrollPane2.setViewportView(jList2);

        jList3.setModel(new javax.swing.AbstractListModel<String>() {
            String[] strings = { "Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4", "Item 5" };
            public int getSize() { return strings.length; }
            public String getElementAt(int i) { return strings[i]; }
        });
        jScrollPane3.setViewportView(jList3);

        jList4.setModel(new javax.swing.AbstractListModel<String>() {
            String[] strings = { "Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4", "Item 5" };
            public int getSize() { return strings.length; }
            public String getElementAt(int i) { return strings[i]; }
        });
        jScrollPane4.setViewportView(jList4);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
                layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addContainerGap()
                                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                                        .addComponent(BotonImprimir)
                                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                                                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                                                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                                                                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                                                                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                                                                        .addComponent(jLabelCurso)
                                                                                        .addComponent(jLabel1))
                                                                                .addGap(34, 34, 34))
                                                                        .addComponent(jComboBoxZona, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 80, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                                                                .addGap(29, 29, 29))
                                                        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                                                .addComponent(jComboBoxCurso, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 80, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)))
                                                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                                                        .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 85, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                                        .addComponent(jScrollPane2))))
                                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                                .addGap(48, 48, 48)
                                                .addComponent(BotonSalir, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 73, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, false)
                                                        .addComponent(jScrollPane4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                                        .addComponent(jScrollPane3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 80, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))))
                                .addContainerGap(266, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
                layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                                .addGap(36, 36, 36)
                                                .addComponent(jLabelCurso)
                                                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                                                .addComponent(jComboBoxCurso, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                                .addGap(46, 46, 46)
                                                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                                        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                                .addContainerGap()
                                                .addComponent(jScrollPane3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                                .addGap(25, 25, 25)
                                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                                .addComponent(jComboBoxZona, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                                        .addComponent(jScrollPane2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                        .addComponent(jScrollPane4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 35, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                                        .addComponent(BotonImprimir)
                                        .addComponent(BotonSalir))
                                .addGap(35, 35, 35))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>
```

> aca esta el ComboBox y he tratado de multiples forma de conectarlo y que este refleje la informacion desde la base de datos sin embargo en todas ellas he fracasado

```
    private void jComboBoxCursoActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            //Connection cn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/base_de_datos", "root", "Eleazar2019");
            //PreparedStatement pst = cn.prepareStatement("Select * from alumno order by alu_cur");// hasta aca funciona no modificar.
              // TODO add your handling code here:
        try {
            Connection conexion=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/base_de_datos","root" ,"Eleazar2019");
            Statement comando=conexion.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = comando.executeQuery("SELECT alumno FROM alu_cur");

            while(rs.next()){
                this.jComboBoxCurso.addItem(rs.getString("Curso")) ;
            }

            conexion.close();
        } catch(SQLException ex){
            setTitle(ex.toString());
        }
    }
```

> en la unica en la cual no me ha logrado salir mal es en el boton salir jajaj, recurro ante ustdes como el ultimo recurso al no encontrar un problema similar

```
    private void BotonSalirActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        System.exit(WIDTH);         // TODO add your handling code here:
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(tarea7.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(tarea7.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(tarea7.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(tarea7.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new tarea7().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify
    private javax.swing.JButton BotonImprimir;
    private javax.swing.JButton BotonSalir;
    private javax.swing.JComboBox<String> jComboBoxCurso;
    private javax.swing.JComboBox<String> jComboBoxZona;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabelCurso;
    private javax.swing.JList<String> jList1;
    private javax.swing.JList<String> jList2;
    private javax.swing.JList<String> jList3;
    private javax.swing.JList<String> jList4;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane2;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane3;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane4;
    // End of variables declaration
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
      ResultSet rs = comando.executeQuery("SELECT alumno FROM alu_cur");

        while(rs.next()){
            this.jComboBoxCurso.addItem(rs.getString("Curso");

     //En el sql estas pidiendo registros rs a la columna alumno de la tabla
     //alu_cur, y queres llenar el jComboBoxCurso con datos de la columna
     //Curso. tenes que cambiar el sql.
```